# Typo3 - updating domain results in 404 errors

Tags: typo3

I want to change the domain for an existing multi domain Typo3 website.
I updated the baseURL as well as the domain entry for the node and cleared all caches.
Now I get a 404 for every url.

The installation is using an extension called CoolURI. I cleared that cache too and looked into the configuration. I didnt see anything that refers to the hostname.

Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

EDIT: I am using Typo3 6.2

Comment: What happens when you click the `View` button on a page in the backend, is the page loaded with the proper url? What TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: @ChristianFries It's Typo3 6.2. The View button displayed the page correctly when the old domain was set (where the site still exists btw). Now it just displays a blank page without any errors.